# How could i add a binary which need another document to command line?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

My environment is Ubuntu16.04.

The structure of my binary's floder is that:

```
copy
├── creat
├── creat.cpp
├── makeup.sh
├── MODEL.cpp
└── README.md
```

And the `creat` is the binary which i want to add to command line.

The MODEL.cpp is the doc that `creat` need.

In creat.cpp i should open the MODEL.cpp like this:

`in.open("MODEL.cpp");`

but i want anyother who cloned this repo could use it easily.
So i write a shell script `makeup.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
g++ creat.cpp -o creat
sudo cp creat /usr/local/bin
sudo cp MODEL.cpp /usr/local/bin
echo "Now you can try it"
```

But when I use the command `creat`, the terminal told me:

```
Can not find MODEL.cpp
```

But the MODEL.cpp exits in /usr/local/bin.

I don't know what's wrong with that, What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the MODEL.cpp is not present in the current location from where you are executing creat even though both creat and MODEL.cpp are in same folder.

best option is to keep the depend MODEL.cpp file in `/etc` folder.

change this line `in.open("MODEL.cpp");`  to `in.open("/etc/MODEL.cpp");`

so it doesn't matter from where you execute the `creat` binary it will work.

Comment: Thank you very much